# Are there methods to trace text files that were web scrapped, finding the user involved and after the text has been machine translated?

Tags: security, web-scraping, text, steganography

- Information

I’m a bit new and want to create a site with these capabilities but don’t know where to start, please point out if I violated any rules or should write differently.

I’ll a bit specific here, so there is a web novel site where content is hidden behind a subscription.

So you would need to be logged into an account.

The novels are viewed through the site’s viewer which can not be selected/highlighted then copied.

- Question

If you web scrape and download the chapters as .txt files then machine translated using like Google Translate, is there a way to track the uploader of the MTL or when the MTL file is shared?

Of similar nature there are aggregator sites that have non-MTL’d novels on them, but the translation teams have hidden lines which tell readers to go to their official site. The lines aren’t on the official site though, only when it has been copied. How is that possible?

I’ve slightly read about JWT, and I’m assuming they can find the user when they’re on the website but what about in the text?

- Additional Question (if above is possible, don’t have to answer this just curious)

If it is possible to embed like some identifying token, is there a way to break it by perhaps converting it into an encrypted epub?

Comment: Suppose the site had exactly two users, A and B.  Logs show that both A and B looked at a certain novel N, and N became available in `.txt` form on the Internet. Looking at the text of the novel, in plain text form, how would you know whether it came from A or B?

Comment: You have to inject watermarks into the text which survive OCR. This means changing some wording in the novel so that it is a little different for each user.

Comment: Kaz is right. When you have multiple users which access the same content and you need to identify who leaked what, the content needs to have unique differences for each user. The what and how depends on what issue you're trying to address. For the distribution of digital files, injecting some unique data will do. Text steganography could be done with injecting invisible space characters, or substituting homoglyphs. Both of these are easy to attack/inspect, but it gives you a starting point. For MT text, you need something that will survive the translation in a unique way.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I understand thank you very much that’s given me some ideas.